# Defining a list of strings as synonyms for a multiword string

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to provide variations of field "title" as its synonyms. I expect that if a user searches for the exact title or any of its variations, this particular document should be returned as first.

eg. I have many faq documents. one of those is

[faq document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbIu1.png)

below is the required faq with its synonymous questions

[my csv dump with question variations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPudB.png)

I read about complexities that arise in case of multi word synonyms. Can anybody suggest how can I map all those question variations as equivalent to the actual question and referring to the same document?

One of the solutions that I thought of is, adding all ques variations as another property field in my index and while querying (using query more_like_this) providing title(here it refers to actual title of question faq) and ques variations list.

Below is my code for indexing, ingested data and querying:

```
PUT faq { "mappings": { "articles": { "properties": { "title": { "type": "string" }, "ques_var": { "type": "string" }, "detail": { "type": "string" }, "detail_html": { "type": "string" }, "account_id": { "type": "long" } } } } }
```

Here my "title" would be "How to log in into facebook?"

My "ques_var" would be ["facebook login?", "where to login for facebook", "do i need to sign up for logging into facebook"]

And my query is like this below:

```
eq.query(Query.more_like_this([constants.TITLE, constants.QUES_VAR], input_data[constants.QUERY],min_term_freq=options.faq_min_term_freq,min_doc_freq=options.faq_min_doc_freq))
```

kindly suggest me if this approach is right. Further this approach doesn't give same IDF(Relevance score) for question variations and title

Answer (score 0):

ElasticSearch version 5.4 has new built in auto suggester for this.

Please refer [You complete me :)](https://www.elastic.co/blog/you-complete-me) . This is the best article you can find to create an auto suggest plugin using elasticsearch.

PS: It does support synonyms.

Demo:
Taking an example from the same article:

If 'courtyard' and 'marriot' are two words which are synonyms of each other. You can specify the same in the suggester settings like:

```
 "analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "suggest_synonyms": {
      "type":      "custom",
      "tokenizer": "lowercase",
      "filter":    [ "my_synonyms" ]
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "my_synonyms": {
      "type":     "synonym",
      "synonyms": [ "courtyard, marriot" ]
    }
  }
}
},
```

And create mappings and enable synonym suggestion in the following way:

```
"mappings": {
"hotel" : {
  "properties" : {
    "name" : { "type" : "string" },
    "city" : { "type" : "string" },
    "name_suggest" : {
      "type" :            "completion",
      "index_analyzer" :  "suggest_synonyms",
      "search_analyzer" : "suggest_synonyms"
    }
  } 
}}
```

Here, auto suggestion is done on field 'name_suggest'

Now, Index few docs like this:

```
curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/hotels/hotel/3?refresh=true' -d '
{
  "name" :         "Courtyard Hotel",
  "city" :         "Munich",
  "name_suggest" : "Courtyard Hotel"
}'
curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/hotels/hotel/3?refresh=true' -d '
{
  "name" :         "Marriot Hotel",
  "city" :         "Munich",
  "name_suggest" : "Marriot Hotel"
}'
```

Now if you search for 'Courtyard' in the auto suggest, it will also return Marriot Hotel as we have specified 'Courtyard' & 'Marriot' as synonyms :)

Comment: Here is a working demo of elasticsearch's auto suggester: http://www.motorsingh.com . Something I have worked on :) The suggestions are returned from the elasticsearch indexes.